# Wirecloud + IDM issues

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

All of a sudden, while everything was working perfectly for more than 9 months, as of late it seems that authentication against IDM is failing. Specifically, i am getting an error 500 (Internal Server Error), no other details provided.

In my settings, nothing is changed, the relevant sections being:

```
FIWARE_IDM_SERVER = "https://account.lab.fi-ware.org"
FIWARE_APP_ID = "<APP_ID>"
FIWARE_APP_SECRET = "<APP_SECRET>"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'wirecloud.fiware.social_auth_backend.FiwareBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIWARE Lab's account server address changed from `https://account.lab.fi-ware.org` to `https://account.lab.fiware.org` (note the dash in fi-ware). `https://account.lab.fi-ware.org` has been configured to redirect to the new address, but Python 2 doesn't support SNI by default making this requests fails before taking into account the redirection. The easiest solution is updating the `FIWARE_IDM_SERVER` setting using the new address.

See this [link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py) for more info about python not supporting SNI and how to enable it.